# Data Migrations of two databases having same structure but different data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working in application of data migration of two databases having same structure but different data. In my database there are lots of tables which are referenced with foreign key.

I need to populate all the tables in such a way where all parent tables will come first then child tables.

```
Ex. 

Suppose I have three tables TABLE_1, TABLE_2 & TABLE_3

1. TABLE_1 is parent table for TABLE_3
2. TABLE_3 is Parent table for TABLE_2 

then the query should produce the below sequence

TABLE_1
TABLE_3
TABLE_2
```

I have tried with system tables provided in SQL Server but can not achieve the desired result. Can you please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have permission to drop the foreign keys, insert the data and then restore the foreign keys?  (warning: always make a backup first)

Comment: well, I can disable all foreign keys too but I believe It should not be like that as it can be a problem with data consistency.

Comment: Very true.  If your data is inconsistent, it will break your FKs.  However, if the data is inconsistent, then inserting it (with the FKs on) won't work either.  When you said it was coming from an existing source, it sounded like that source might already be consistent.  If not, I would attempt to resolve the data BEFORE trying to import it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem to solve - there's no built in way for doing it.

You could add all the tables to a database diagram and see if you can deduce the processing order from that, perhaps?

Have a look at the results from SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys too.